# What is .profile file in AIX Platform?

Tags: .profile

In my home path, there is one file named ".profile". It contained ORACLE_HOME path and all.
What is the use of .profile file? Is it similar to .cshrc file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is similar.  `.profile` is the shell startup script for the class of shells derived from the original [Bourne shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).  This includes (but probably isn't limited to) the Bourne shell, Bash, the Korn shell, and the Z shell.

Answer (score 1):

`.profile` is to `sh` as `.login` is to `csh`, i.e. commands in it are read and executed by the Bourne shell (and compatible shells like `bash`) at startup for interactive login shells.